# Вызов процедуры SQLSERVER из JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, процедуры

Здравствуйте.есть процедура (Структура на картинке).Он принимает `VARCHAR` и выдает `VARCHAR`.И у меня не получается сделать элементарный запрос к этой процедуре из `JDBC`... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt;
        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            System.out.println("podkluchenie k baze...");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://0.0.0.0:0000;" +"databaseName=blabla-blabla;user=blabla;password=blabla";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

            System.out.println("est konnect...");
            System.out.println("sozdanie zaprosa...");
            cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call xml_parser(?)}");
            cstmt.setString (1, "<xml><action>login</action><login>test</login><password>147852</password></xml>");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cstmt.execute();   


            String s = cstmt.getString(1);
            System.out.println(s);
            cstmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("PoKAAAA!");
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста...
stackTrace :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Формальный параметр "@request" не объявлен как параметр OUTPUT, однако текущий параметр был выдан в результате запроса.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1672)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:460)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:387)
    at paket.JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
PoKAAAA!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
    cstmt = con.prepareCall("{? = call xml_parser(?)}");
    cstmt.setString (2, "<xml><action>login</action><login>test</login><password>147852</password></xml>");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

Comment: спасибо.что то у меня 0.выводит.щас посмотрю в отладке

Comment: перепробовал все до чего мог додуматься.Не работает ..